# Marklogic: what are field range query and path range query cts functions using xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have been following the documentation to understand cts:field-range-query and cts:path-range-query. These are the links i used to understand.
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:field-range-query
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:path-range-query

In cts:path-range-query, i didnt understand the output. How do you compare a string with < or >?

```
cts:search(doc(),cts:path-range-query("/name/fname",">","Jim"),"filtered")
 =>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name><fname>John</fname><mname>Rob</mname><lname>Goldings</lname></name>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name><fname>Ooi</fname><mname>Ben</mname><lname>Fu</lname></name>
```

In cts:field-range-query, here aswell i didnt get the output.

```
ts:search(doc(),cts:field-range-query("aname",">","Jim Kurla"));

(:
  returns the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>
  <fname>John</fname>
  <mname>Rob</mname>
  <lname>Goldings</lname>
</name>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>
  <fname>Ooi</fname>
  <mname>Ben</mname>
  <lname>Fu</lname>
</name>
:)
```

Sorry, if it is silly but i have been trying to understand this little thing since several days but somehow i don't get it. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String comparison is based on alphanumeric comparison. It actually depends on the collation, but the default is based on Unicode (UCA Root Collation with case and diacritic sensitivity). `A` comes before `B`, but `a` comes after `B`, and also `alpha` comes after `Zeta`. More confusingly, `10` comes before `2` as well.

In your examples the path query only looks at `fname` where `Jim` comes before both `John` and `Ooi`.

The second example is likely a field with multiple paths, including `fname`, `mname`, and `lname`. The `>` satisfies if there is any name value in the document that is larger than `Jim`. `Goldings`, `Ben`, and `Fu` come before `Jim` alphabetically, but there are other names like `John` and `Ooi` that come after. So that returns both those values as well.

It is more fun to repeat the queries with `Lee`. The path query will then return 1 result only (the second), but the field is likely still returning both.